# Golang table webscraping

Tags: api, go, web-scraping, html-table, goquery

I have a code as below to scrape the specific cell value from html table. You can go to https://www.haremaltin.com/altin-fiyatlari website and search "satis__ATA_ESKI" on inspect mode to see that value. I am beginner on golang and did my best but unfortunately I couldn't get that value. Is there anybody to help me? Btw they don't have a community api. And one more thing, add time.sleep to wait for page to be loaded. If it returns "-" it is because page wasn't be loaded yet

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"log"
"net/http"

"github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

func main() {
   url := "https://www.haremaltin.com/altin-fiyatlari"

   resp, err := http.Get(url)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   defer resp.Body.Close()
   if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
       log.Fatalf("failed to fetch data: %d %s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status)
   }

   doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }

   doc.Find("tr__ATA_ESKI tr").Each(func(j int, tr *goquery.Selection) {
      data := []string{}
      tr.Find("td").Each(func(ix int, td *goquery.Selection) {
           e := td.Text()
           data = append(data, e)
           fmt.Println(data)
      })
   })
}
```

SOLUTION:

You can see the answer below and if you want you can check [image: the source code] to see why this kind of solution is used

Btw we can use iteration to fetch the specific value from map. I have a code for this too. But if you have any easier method just comment please

```
for _, v := range data { // we need value part of the map
    m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}) // we need the convert the map 
                                    // into interface for iteration
    if !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Error %T", v)
    }
    for k, l := range m {
        if k == "ATA_ESKI"{ // the value we want is inside of this map
            a, ok := l.(map[string]interface{}) // interface convert again
            if !ok {
                fmt.Printf("Error %T", v)
            }
            for b,c := range a{
                if b == "satis"{ // the value we want
                    fmt.Println("Price is", c)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full solution with iteration below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fecthData()
}

func fecthData() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    body := strings.NewReader("dil_kodu=tr")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", 
"https://www.haremaltin.com/dashboard/ajax/doviz", body)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Set("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    var data map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for _, v := range data {
        m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
        if !ok {
            fmt.Printf("Error %T", v)
        }
        for k, l := range m {
            if k == "ATA_ESKI" {
                a, ok := l.(map[string]interface{})
                if !ok {
                    fmt.Printf("Error %T", v)
                }
                for b, c := range a {
                    if b == "satis" {
                        fmt.Println("Price", c)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return data, nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch via http Post request. Do not forget to add X-Requested-With header to request.

```
func fecthData() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    body := strings.NewReader("dil_kodu=tr")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://www.haremaltin.com/dashboard/ajax/doviz", body)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Set("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not expecting a solution like this. After checking source code a light bulb went on in my head. Thank you so much indeed

Answer (score 1):

Since the table is powered by javascript, i would suggest you use a different approach. Here's why.

What you're really scraping is

```bash
curl https://www.haremaltin.com/altin-fiyatlari > out.html
```

this web page. You can run this curl in a terminal and get the exact same reply as go's rest request ( exact is a strong word, most of the time, for sure this case )

As you can see no values are present in that `out.html` file you created, thats why your go script isn't returning any values.

You need to have javascript running to populate the page, so you can then scrape it.

I've used this https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp in a couple projects with great success. By using this tool your workflow will look something like..

1. open headless browser
2. go to url
3. dump pages html
4. parse with goquery
5. print your response

Comment: actually.. if you look at the network traffic you may find what you're looking for, and can use a much simpler approach..

Comment: I recommend you check the solution

Comment: yup, thats it. and the data should be in json

Comment: Actually I tried to convert it into json but failed. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @eyup.tatar what error are you seeing?

Comment: it says map[string]interface value cannot be converted into json, it was something like that.